# How to prove using Zorn's lemma that if $X$ has at least two elements, then is a 1-1 function $H\colon X\to X$ such that $H(x)\neq x$ for all $x$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is the problem.

Let $X$ be an arbitrary set having at least two elements. Show that there is 1-1 function $H: X \to X$ such that for all $x \in X$, $H(x) \neq x$, by using Zorn's Lemma.

To prove by using Zorn's Lemma, I have to construct an ordered set

Comment: I'd try the set of elements $(A,B,f)$, where $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$ and $f$ is a bijective function from $A$ to $B$ such that $f(x)\neq x$ for every $x$. I'm not sure it will work though. Maybe it will be necessary to impose $A=B$.

Comment: I like this question, but, ["I have no idea"](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933) has a tendency to attract close votes on math.stackexchange. Some idea, *any* idea, is better than "I have no idea".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Zorn's lemma to get a maximal family of pairwise disjoint two-element subsets of $X$. If you're lucky, these pairs will cover all of $X$ and you can define $H$ to be the function that maps each $x\in X$ to the other element of its pair. If you're unlucky and there's some $a\in X$ not covered by your maximal family of pairs, then there's only one such $a$ by maximality. Adjoin $a$ to one of your pairs, say $\{p,q\}$, define $H$ on the $3$-element set $\{a,p,q\}$ by $a\mapsto p\mapsto q\mapsto a$, and define $H$ on all your other pairs as in the "lucky" case.